# ElasticSearch Search query performance issue when index size is growing

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I'm experiencing search performance degradation when index size is growing. Eg: For a given query, i'm getting 3500 RPS (Request per second) with 1M documents on index, whereas with 6M documents on index is giving me 1200 RPS.  Each document size on index is average of 500 bytes. Tried with following different cluster configs, and the behavior is same in both cases.

Elastic Search version: 1.2.1

Cluster 1 configuration: 4 node cluster
   2 Routers  Nodes: VMs with 4 Core CPU, 4 GB Ram, 20GB disk
   2 Data Nodes: Physicals with 32 Core CPU, 198GB Ram (24G allocated to ES process), 250 GB disk
   Number of shards for index : 3 and 1 replica

Cluster 2 configuration: 7 node cluster
   2 Routers  Nodes: VMs with 4 Core CPU, 4 GB Ram, 20GB disk
   2 Data Nodes: VMs with 8 Core CPU, 48GB Ram (24G allocated to ES process), 250 GB local storage
   Number of shards for index : 3 and 1 replica

In addition to search query performance issue, i observed that the Data nodes CPU is always spiking to 100% on all core.

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Gopi